# 'Expected Global Line.' exception while loading solution using Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm learning Roslyn and trying it out for the first time. I've written a small code snippet to load a solution and get a reference to a workspace.

```
IWorkspace workspace = Workspace.LoadSolution(solutionPath);

foreach (IProject project in workspace.CurrentSolution.Projects)
{
    CommonCompilation objCompilation = project.GetCompilation();
}
return workspace;
```

But I'm getting an exception in the first line. The exception details are given below.

> Message : **Expected Global Line.**
>
> stack trace :
>  at
>   Roslyn.Services.Host.SolutionFile.ParseGlobal(TextReader reader)
>   at Roslyn.Services.Host.SolutionFile.Parse(TextReader reader)
>  at
>   Roslyn.Services.Host.LoadedWorkspace.LoadSolution(SolutionId
>   solutionId, String filePath)
>  at
>   Roslyn.Services.Host.LoadedWorkspace.OpenSolution(String fileName)
>   at Roslyn.Services.Host.LoadedWorkspace.LoadSolution(String
>   solutionFileName, String configuration, String platform, Boolean
>   enableFileTracking)
>  at
>   Roslyn.Services.Workspace.LoadSolution(String solutionFileName, String
>   configuration, String platform, Boolean enableFileTracking)
>  at
>   Ros2.Program.GetWorkspace(String solutionPath) in
>   c:\users\amnatu\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\Ros2\Ros2\Program.cs:line 30

I [referred to this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/df9af25e-75fc-47e6-9704-8aa89817857c/systemexception-expected-global-line) which shows the same issue that I faced. However, the solution of removing the space between `EndProject` and `Global` isn't really applicable in my case as my solution file doesn't have any space between them.

Am I missing anything here?
Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What version of Roslyn are you using? It looks like it's the outdated 2012 CTP. You should probably use the new `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the delayed response. The comment by @JoshVarty helped me understand the issue.

I was indeed using the out dated version and had to use the latest `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` library. After I made these changes and updated all classes accordingly, everything worked perfectly.

Thanks JoshVarty.!

Comment: Did you use the smae classes and method calls, and just replaced the roslyn references by codeanalysis refs?