# 'Expected Global Line.' exception while loading solution

Tags: roslyn

```
    IWorkspace workspace = Workspace.LoadSolution(solutionPath);
var documents = workspace.GetProjectBy(projectName);
```

Getting exception in 1st line.

Checked the link [ ['Expected Global Line.' exception while loading solution using Roslyn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31781140/expected-global-line-exception-while-loading-solution-using-roslyn) ]. But this didnt help me.
I have the latest Code analysis dll and no space issue in the solution path.
Please help me finding what is missing here.

Comment: @Paulo - The exception is 'Expected Global Line'. I am not able to underastand whats is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the old NuGet packages before we renamed them. The [latest packages that are named Microsoft.CodeAnalysis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis) should not have this bug.